# Hide dates after maximum / before minimum in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` with a `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` set. The default UI of the date picker shows all dates, including those before the minimum and after the maximum. If the user spins to an out-of-bounds date, the picker does spin back - but this is not a great user experience. Can I make it so that the picker simply doesn't display out-of-bounds dates?

In my case, this is particularly important because my app deals with historic events. The date picker starts at the current date and allows users to spin back in time. It's faintly ridiculous in this situation to show tomorrow's date below the current date.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope! Nothing out there, it seems.